# Google Directory API etags differ when the data is exactly the same

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, etag

**Background:**

I want to utilize Etags (that I thought was a hash of the received data) for validation.

Google Directory API let's me specify exactly what fields is required and sends along the etag, out-of-the-box.

**Issue:**

These etags differ between list- and get-operations. The data is exactly the same. I've tested user and org-units. I think they should be the same. What are etags used for?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#ResourceVersioning), an [ETag](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) is an identifier that specifies a particular version of a particular entry. The server attaches an ETag to entry and feed elements that it sends to clients. When an entry or feed changes, its ETag changes as well.

> **Resource versioning (ETags)**
>
> Sometimes you need to be able to refer to a specific version of a
>   particular entry.
>
> This is important in two cases in particular:
>
> - Doing a "conditional retrieval," in which your client requests an entry, and the server sends the entry only if it has changed since the last time the client requested it.
> - Ensuring that multiple clients don't inadvertently overwrite one another's changes. The Data APIs do this by making updates and deletes fail if the client specifies an old version identifier for the entry.
>
> The Google Data APIs handle both of these cases using ETags, a standard part of HTTP.